# Good textbook for a one semester "probability and statistics" course for computer enginering 1st year

Tags: probability

I am looking for a good textbook for a one semester "probability and statistics" course for computer engineering 1st year university students (e.g. no calculus). Can you suggest?

Calculus should not be a prerequisite: Our program has probability and statistics on the first semester of first year. That means students will be taking this course alongside calculus. Hence they will not know calculus. This rules out a lot of excellent probability and statistics textbooks.

No high level programming: Even though our students are computer engineering students, they will not know programming.

If possible, the book should be related to the use cases of computer engineers.

I am aware of similar "good book" questions in this site, but I think my situation is specific enough to ask another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two textbooks along the lines you requested:

1)Barrow M., [*Statistics for Economics, Accounting and Business Studies*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistics-Economics-Accounting-Business-Studies/dp/0273764322/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409386492&sr=8-1&keywords=michael%20barrow%20statistics), Prentice Hall, Financial Times.

2)Newbold P., Carlson W., Thorne B., *[Statistics for Business and Economics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0273767062/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i5?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-3&pf_rd_r=1FTFWQJ7EZ711KQZBM34&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=455333147&pf_rd_i=468294)*, Pearson.

Topics covered include: basic notions of probability, some distribution theory, confidence intervals, hypothesis testing, linear regression and ANOVA. Both assume no prior calculus knowledge and thus are ideal for a first pass. I hope this helps.